# class CustomString is public, should be declared in a file named CustomString.java public class CustomString { ^ 1 error

Tags: java

I'm getting this error.

here is my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;

public class CustomString {

    // instance attributes
    String myString;
    boolean isSet;

    /**
     * initializing the instance attribute
     */
    public CustomString() {
        myString = null;
        isSet = false;

    }
```

Comment: Well, is your file named `CustomString.java`? Because the error message is stating that it is not

Comment: Check your file name, if you are using public class then file name and class name should be same.

Answer (score 0):

1. rename your file to CustomString.java
2. you are missing a `}`at the end of your code

Comment: i just posted half the code

Comment: and the file is named as CustomString.java tho